# Oneway conference calling through asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I am new to Asterisk and Voip. I wanted to accomplish a following small thing using Asterisk.

### Description

1. Asterisk is used as server
2. Several Voip clients. (Two types of clients possible. One which can start a conference call, other can't call but can only hear.) Only caller client can start/end this call.
3. The call can't be longer then a particular time.

Is it possible through Asterisk. How does asterisk help to implement this scenario. What does I need to learn? Any web links will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all that with Asterisk and ConfBridge:

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+ConfBridge

Use the following options to accomplish your objectives:

'A' — Set marked mode
'm' — Set initially muted.
'w' — Wait until the marked user enters the conference

You can use another dial plan function: TIMEOUT(absolute) to limit the conference duration.

To start I would look at the examples in the above link.